# Select from another table if original table is empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

How can I make it so that the query will select from another table if first table is empty.

Here is the current query in my C# program, I'm using SQL Server.

```
private const string sql = @'SELECT TOP (1) (LOCALTIME) from dbo.[devicemessage] order by (localtime) desc;
```

So what this code does is it gets the the value in the localtime column from the top 1 row which is arranged in localtime desc; the latest timing.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
If dbo.[devicemessage] is empty select top (1) (localtime) from dbo.[devicemessagehistory] order by (localtime) desc,
if table dbo.[devicemessage] not empty, get from dbo.[devicemessage].
```

Is it possible to do it in one query string as I am using it in C# .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just union the 2 tables together with a `not exists` condition. This allows you to select from 2 tables in the same query but only gives a result from the second table if no rows exist in the first table:

```
select top 1 localtime
from (
  select localtime
  from dbo.[devicemessage]
  union all
  select localtime
  from dbo.[devicemessagehistory]
  where not exists (select 1 from dbo.[devicemessage])
) X
order by localtime desc;
```

Answer (score 3):

Select `isnull()` or `coalesce()` will get your `max()` `devicemessage` `LOCALTIME` if available and if not, will select your `devicemessagehistory`.

If you only have 2 conditions `isnull()` is enough, but if you have multiple conditions, I suggest to use `coalesce()`.

```
select isnull(
    (select max(LOCALTIME) from [devicemessage]),
        (select max(LOCALTIME) from [devicemessagehistory]))

select coalesce(
    (select max(LOCALTIME) from [devicemessage]),
        (select max(LOCALTIME) from [devicemessagehistory]))
```

using `order by`

```
select isnull(
    (select TOP 1 localtime from dbo.[devicemessage] order by localtime desc),
        (select TOP 1 localtime from dbo.[devicemessagehistory] order by localtime desc))
```

Comment: And what is your recommendation for whether to use `isnull` or `coalesce`? Hardy need to provide both options just the one you prefer.

Comment: `select top 1 localtime order by localtime desc`, is going to be the same thing as `select max(localtime)`

Comment: @Metal `coalesce` is also the ANSI SQL standard, whereas `isnull` is SQL Server specific.